# Multiply all columns of a multi-indexed DataFrame by appropriate values in a Series

Tags: python, pandas

I feel like this one should be obvious, but I'm a bit stuck.

I have a DataFrame (`df`) with a 3-level MultiIndex on the rows.  One of the levels of the MultiIndex is `ccy` and represents the currency that denominates the information contained in that row.  Each row has 3 columns of data.

I would like to convert all of the data to be denominated in a reference currency (say USD).  To do this, I have a series (`forex`) that contains foreign exchange rates for the relevant currencies.

So the goal is simple: multiply all the data in each row of `df` by the value of `forex` that corresponds to the `ccy` entry of the index of that row in `df`.

The mechanical setup looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import itertools

np.random.seed(0)

tuples = list(itertools.product(
                                list('abd'), 
                                ['one', 'two', 'three'], 
                                ['USD', 'EUR', 'GBP']
                                ))

np.random.shuffle(tuples)

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples[:-10], names=['letter', 'number', 'ccy'])

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(idx), 3), index=idx,
                  columns=['val_1', 'val_2', 'val_3'])

forex = pd.Series({'USD': 1.0,
                   'EUR': 1.3,
                   'GBP': 1.7})
```

I can get what I need by running:

```
df.apply(lambda col: col.mul(forex, level='ccy'), axis=0)
```

But it seems weird to me that I would need to use `pd.DataFrame.apply` in such a simple case.  I would have expected the following syntax (or something very much like it) to work:

```
df.mul(forex, level='ccy', axis=0)
```

but that gives me:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Clearly the `apply` method isn't a disaster.  But just seems weird that I couldn't figure out the syntax for doing this directly across all the columns with `mul`.  Is there a more direct way to handle this?  If not, is there an intuitive reason the `mul` syntax shouldn't be enhanced to work this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This now works in master/0.14. See the issue: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/6682

```
In [11]: df.mul(forex,level='ccy',axis=0)
Out[11]: 
                      val_1     val_2     val_3
letter number ccy                              
a      one    GBP -2.172854  2.443530 -0.132098
d      three  USD  1.089630  0.096543  1.418667
b      two    GBP  1.986064  1.610216  1.845328
       three  GBP  4.049782 -0.690240  0.452957
a      two    GBP -2.304713 -0.193974 -1.435192
b      one    GBP  1.199589 -0.677936 -1.406234
d      two    GBP -0.706766 -0.891671  1.382272
b      two    EUR -0.298026  2.810233 -1.244011
d      one    EUR  0.087504  0.268448 -0.593946
              GBP -1.801959  1.045427  2.430423
b      three  EUR -0.275538 -0.104438  0.527017
a      one    EUR  0.154189  1.630738  1.844833
b      one    EUR -0.967013 -3.272668 -1.959225
d      three  GBP  1.953429 -2.029083  1.939772
              EUR  1.962279  1.388108 -0.892566
a      three  GBP  0.025285 -0.638632 -0.064980
              USD  0.367974 -0.044724 -0.302375

[17 rows x 3 columns]
```

Here is a another way to do it (also requires master/0.14)

```
In [127]: df = df.sortlevel()

In [128]: df
Out[128]: 
                      val_1     val_2     val_3
letter number ccy                              
a      one    EUR  0.118607  1.254414  1.419102
              GBP -1.278149  1.437371 -0.077705
       three  GBP  0.014873 -0.375666 -0.038224
              USD  0.367974 -0.044724 -0.302375
       two    GBP -1.355714 -0.114103 -0.844231
b      one    EUR -0.743856 -2.517437 -1.507096
              GBP  0.705641 -0.398786 -0.827197
       three  EUR -0.211952 -0.080337  0.405398
              GBP  2.382224 -0.406024  0.266445
       two    EUR -0.229251  2.161717 -0.956931
              GBP  1.168273  0.947186  1.085487
d      one    EUR  0.067311  0.206499 -0.456881
              GBP -1.059976  0.614957  1.429661
       three  EUR  1.509445  1.067775 -0.686589
              GBP  1.149076 -1.193578  1.141042
              USD  1.089630  0.096543  1.418667
       two    GBP -0.415745 -0.524512  0.813101

[17 rows x 3 columns]

idx = pd.IndexSlice

In [129]: pd.concat([ df.loc[idx[:,:,x],:]*v for x,v in forex.iteritems() ])
Out[129]: 
                      val_1     val_2     val_3
letter number ccy                              
a      one    EUR  0.154189  1.630738  1.844833
b      one    EUR -0.967013 -3.272668 -1.959225
       three  EUR -0.275538 -0.104438  0.527017
       two    EUR -0.298026  2.810233 -1.244011
d      one    EUR  0.087504  0.268448 -0.593946
       three  EUR  1.962279  1.388108 -0.892566
a      one    GBP -2.172854  2.443530 -0.132098
       three  GBP  0.025285 -0.638632 -0.064980
       two    GBP -2.304713 -0.193974 -1.435192
b      one    GBP  1.199589 -0.677936 -1.406234
       three  GBP  4.049782 -0.690240  0.452957
       two    GBP  1.986064  1.610216  1.845328
d      one    GBP -1.801959  1.045427  2.430423
       three  GBP  1.953429 -2.029083  1.939772
       two    GBP -0.706766 -0.891671  1.382272
a      three  USD  0.367974 -0.044724 -0.302375
d      three  USD  1.089630  0.096543  1.418667

[17 rows x 3 columns]
```

Here's another way via merging

```
In [36]: f = forex.to_frame('value')

In [37]: f.index.name =  'ccy'

In [38]: pd.merge(df.reset_index(),f.reset_index(),on='ccy')
Out[38]: 
   letter number  ccy     val_1     val_2     val_3  value
0       a    one  GBP -1.278149  1.437371 -0.077705    1.7
1       b    two  GBP  1.168273  0.947186  1.085487    1.7
2       b  three  GBP  2.382224 -0.406024  0.266445    1.7
3       a    two  GBP -1.355714 -0.114103 -0.844231    1.7
4       b    one  GBP  0.705641 -0.398786 -0.827197    1.7
5       d    two  GBP -0.415745 -0.524512  0.813101    1.7
6       d    one  GBP -1.059976  0.614957  1.429661    1.7
7       d  three  GBP  1.149076 -1.193578  1.141042    1.7
8       a  three  GBP  0.014873 -0.375666 -0.038224    1.7
9       d  three  USD  1.089630  0.096543  1.418667    1.0
10      a  three  USD  0.367974 -0.044724 -0.302375    1.0
11      b    two  EUR -0.229251  2.161717 -0.956931    1.3
12      d    one  EUR  0.067311  0.206499 -0.456881    1.3
13      b  three  EUR -0.211952 -0.080337  0.405398    1.3
14      a    one  EUR  0.118607  1.254414  1.419102    1.3
15      b    one  EUR -0.743856 -2.517437 -1.507096    1.3
16      d  three  EUR  1.509445  1.067775 -0.686589    1.3

[17 rows x 7 columns]
```

Comment: Jeff, thanks for the reply.  And sorry for highlighting something that's already been flagged as an issue.  For what it's worth, I think my `apply` column-wise solution, above, is easier to read than the `pd.concat...` method in your `[129]`.  What do you think?

Comment: using ``apply`` will be much slower.

Comment: What is `pd.IndexSlice` above?

Comment: look at the docs; its a grouping class for multi-index slicing

Comment: Cool...new post 0.13...that seems like a great feature add.

Comment: yep (you can also assign to it), makes lots of things easy with nice syntax. As I said what you want here *should* work, its almost their too.

Comment: I was also thinking about approaching this using `Series.map` (i.e. treat the `ccy` level of the index as a `Series` and use `map` to convert it to a series of the foreign-exchange rates and then multiply the original dataframe by that series (which would be like-indexed).  But it's a bit annoying since a level of an index isn't a series (without a little bit of effort).

Comment: I put up a (almost there) a way to do this via merging.

Comment: Yeah, had been thinking that way, too.  Seems like there are plenty of fast-ish, readable-ish ways to do this.  So sounds like it will be great when the 'right' answer makes it into master.

Comment: I know I know.  I'm light years away from making something this complicated my first PR.

Comment: This turned out to be easy, give this a try: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/6682

Comment: Another way to merge without resetting index and converting `forex` to a dataframe:
`df.merge(forex.rename('exchange_rate'), how='inner', left_on='ccy', right_index=True)`

Comment: Adding to my pervious comment, more shorter way is:
`df.join(forex.rename('exchange_rate'), on='ccy')`